# android disable two buttons when either one of them is clicked

Tags: android

I have two buttons, addBtn and declineBtn. When either of them is clicked I want to disable these two buttons. I keep getting

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.Button.setEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference

The problem is that if I click on decline button, then onClicklistener v.findViewById cannot find the add button. Any help would be appreciated

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;
        if(rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friend_request_item, parent, false);
        }
        final FriendRequest request = getItem(position);
        TextView userId = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        userId.setText(request.getRequesterId());

        Button acceptBtn = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        acceptBtn.setTag(request.getRequesterId());
        Button declineBtn = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        declineBtn.setTag(request.getRequesterId());

        acceptBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Button AddBtn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.addbutton1);
                AddBtn.setEnabled(false);
                Button declineBtn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.devlinebutton2);
                declineBtn.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
        declineBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Button AddBtn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.addbutton1);
                AddBtn.setEnabled(false);
                v.setEnabled(false);
                Button declineBtn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.declinebutton2);
                declineBtn.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
        return rowView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `v` to call `findViewById()`. Just write `(Button)  findViewById(R.id.button1)`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the buttons are inside the `rowView` so I think you should use `rowView.findViewById()` instead of `v.findViewById()`